# zephyr RTOS (STM32) custom node not imported: undefined reference to `__device_dts_ord_xx`

Tags: stm32, device-tree, zephyr-rtos

This is definitely doable, because I have been able to do it on another PC, but on this PC that I am working, I have ran into issue, it seems that I have forgotten something, but I cannot be sure why.

Once I run `zephyr build` after writing the following code:

```
const struct device *dev = DEVICE_DT_GET(DT_NODELABEL(mygpio));
if (!device_is_ready(dev)) {
    printk("unready");
}
```

I run into following:
`` undefined reference to `__device_dts_ord_17' ``

I have been following this guide on how to sort the issue but to no avail: https://docs.zephyrproject.org/latest/build/dts/troubleshooting.html

The following file is nucleo_f334r8.overlay file

```
/ {
    compatible = "st,stm32f334r8-nucleo";

    mygpio: mygpio {
        compatible = "zephyr,mygpio";
        status = "okay";
        gpios = <&gpioa 12 (GPIO_ACTIVE_HIGH)>,
                <&gpiob 5 (GPIO_ACTIVE_HIGH)>,
                <&gpiob 10 (GPIO_ACTIVE_HIGH)>,
                <&gpiob 6 (GPIO_ACTIVE_HIGH)>;
    };
};

&usart2 {
    status = "okay";
};

&timers2 {
    status = "okay";
    st,prescaler = <4095>;
    counter: counter {
        compatible = "st,stm32-counter";
        status = "okay";
    };
};

&gpioa {
    status = "okay";
};

&gpiob {
    status = "okay";
};
```

The following is my prj.conf file

```
CONFIG_SERIAL=y
CONFIG_UART_INTERRUPT_DRIVEN=y
CONFIG_COUNTER=y
CONFIG_COUNTER_TIMER_STM32=y
CONFIG_RING_BUFFER=y
CONFIG_GPIO=y
```

I have defined a binding in my dts/bindings

```
description: |
  mygpio

compatible: "zephyr,mygpio"

include: base.yaml

properties:
  gpios:
    type: phandle-array
    required: true
    description: List of gpios
```

inside of build folder, inside of zephyr.dts, my node is successfully generated:

```
    mygpio: mygpio {
        compatible = "zephyr,mygpio";
        status = "okay";
        gpios = < &gpioa 0xc 0x0 >, < &gpiob 0x5 0x0 >, < &gpiob 0xa 0x0 >, < &gpiob 0x6 0x0 >;
    };
```

devicetree_generated.h contains my node

```
...
 *   16  /soc/pin-controller@48000000/gpio@48000400
 *   17  /mygpio
 *   18  /st-morpho-header
...
```

devicetree_generated.h also contains various macroses that assign pins and etc

```
/* Node's full path: */
#define DT_N_S_mygpio_PATH "/mygpio"

/* Node's name with unit-address: */
#define DT_N_S_mygpio_FULL_NAME "mygpio"

/* Node parent (/) identifier: */
#define DT_N_S_mygpio_PARENT DT_N

/* Node's index in its parent's list of children: */
#define DT_N_S_mygpio_CHILD_IDX 15

/* Helper macros for child nodes of this node. */
#define DT_N_S_mygpio_FOREACH_CHILD(fn) 
#define DT_N_S_mygpio_FOREACH_CHILD_SEP(fn, sep) 
#define DT_N_S_mygpio_FOREACH_CHILD_VARGS(fn, ...) 
#define DT_N_S_mygpio_FOREACH_CHILD_SEP_VARGS(fn, sep, ...) 
#define DT_N_S_mygpio_FOREACH_CHILD_STATUS_OKAY(fn) 
#define DT_N_S_mygpio_FOREACH_CHILD_STATUS_OKAY_SEP(fn, sep) 
#define DT_N_S_mygpio_FOREACH_CHILD_STATUS_OKAY_VARGS(fn, ...) 
#define DT_N_S_mygpio_FOREACH_CHILD_STATUS_OKAY_SEP_VARGS(fn, sep, ...) 

/* Node's dependency ordinal: */
#define DT_N_S_mygpio_ORD 17
#define DT_N_S_mygpio_ORD_STR_SORTABLE 00017

/* Ordinals for what this node depends on directly: */
#define DT_N_S_mygpio_REQUIRES_ORDS \
    0, /* / */ \
    15, /* /soc/pin-controller@48000000/gpio@48000000 */ \
    16, /* /soc/pin-controller@48000000/gpio@48000400 */

/* Ordinals for what depends directly on this node: */
#define DT_N_S_mygpio_SUPPORTS_ORDS /* nothing */

/* Existence and alternate IDs: */
#define DT_N_S_mygpio_EXISTS 1
#define DT_N_INST_0_zephyr_mygpio DT_N_S_mygpio
#define DT_N_NODELABEL_mygpio     DT_N_S_mygpio

/* Macros for properties that are special in the specification: */
#define DT_N_S_mygpio_REG_NUM 0
#define DT_N_S_mygpio_RANGES_NUM 0
#define DT_N_S_mygpio_FOREACH_RANGE(fn) 
#define DT_N_S_mygpio_IRQ_NUM 0
#define DT_N_S_mygpio_COMPAT_MATCHES_zephyr_mygpio 1
#define DT_N_S_mygpio_COMPAT_VENDOR_IDX_0_EXISTS 1
#define DT_N_S_mygpio_COMPAT_VENDOR_IDX_0 "Zephyr-specific binding"
#define DT_N_S_mygpio_COMPAT_MODEL_IDX_0_EXISTS 1
#define DT_N_S_mygpio_COMPAT_MODEL_IDX_0 "mygpio"
#define DT_N_S_mygpio_STATUS_okay 1

/* Pin control (pinctrl-<i>, pinctrl-names) properties: */
#define DT_N_S_mygpio_PINCTRL_NUM 0

/* Generic property macros: */
#define DT_N_S_mygpio_P_gpios_IDX_0_EXISTS 1
#define DT_N_S_mygpio_P_gpios_IDX_0_PH DT_N_S_soc_S_pin_controller_48000000_S_gpio_48000000
#define DT_N_S_mygpio_P_gpios_IDX_0_VAL_pin 12
#define DT_N_S_mygpio_P_gpios_IDX_0_VAL_pin_EXISTS 1
#define DT_N_S_mygpio_P_gpios_IDX_0_VAL_flags 0
#define DT_N_S_mygpio_P_gpios_IDX_0_VAL_flags_EXISTS 1
#define DT_N_S_mygpio_P_gpios_IDX_1_EXISTS 1
#define DT_N_S_mygpio_P_gpios_IDX_1_PH DT_N_S_soc_S_pin_controller_48000000_S_gpio_48000400
#define DT_N_S_mygpio_P_gpios_IDX_1_VAL_pin 5
#define DT_N_S_mygpio_P_gpios_IDX_1_VAL_pin_EXISTS 1
#define DT_N_S_mygpio_P_gpios_IDX_1_VAL_flags 0
#define DT_N_S_mygpio_P_gpios_IDX_1_VAL_flags_EXISTS 1
#define DT_N_S_mygpio_P_gpios_IDX_2_EXISTS 1
#define DT_N_S_mygpio_P_gpios_IDX_2_PH DT_N_S_soc_S_pin_controller_48000000_S_gpio_48000400
#define DT_N_S_mygpio_P_gpios_IDX_2_VAL_pin 10
#define DT_N_S_mygpio_P_gpios_IDX_2_VAL_pin_EXISTS 1
#define DT_N_S_mygpio_P_gpios_IDX_2_VAL_flags 0
#define DT_N_S_mygpio_P_gpios_IDX_2_VAL_flags_EXISTS 1
#define DT_N_S_mygpio_P_gpios_IDX_3_EXISTS 1
#define DT_N_S_mygpio_P_gpios_IDX_3_PH DT_N_S_soc_S_pin_controller_48000000_S_gpio_48000400
#define DT_N_S_mygpio_P_gpios_IDX_3_VAL_pin 6
#define DT_N_S_mygpio_P_gpios_IDX_3_VAL_pin_EXISTS 1
#define DT_N_S_mygpio_P_gpios_IDX_3_VAL_flags 0
#define DT_N_S_mygpio_P_gpios_IDX_3_VAL_flags_EXISTS 1
#define DT_N_S_mygpio_P_gpios_FOREACH_PROP_ELEM(fn) fn(DT_N_S_mygpio, gpios, 0) \
    fn(DT_N_S_mygpio, gpios, 1) \
    fn(DT_N_S_mygpio, gpios, 2) \
    fn(DT_N_S_mygpio, gpios, 3)
#define DT_N_S_mygpio_P_gpios_FOREACH_PROP_ELEM_SEP(fn, sep) fn(DT_N_S_mygpio, gpios, 0) DT_DEBRACKET_INTERNAL sep \
    fn(DT_N_S_mygpio, gpios, 1) DT_DEBRACKET_INTERNAL sep \
    fn(DT_N_S_mygpio, gpios, 2) DT_DEBRACKET_INTERNAL sep \
    fn(DT_N_S_mygpio, gpios, 3)
#define DT_N_S_mygpio_P_gpios_FOREACH_PROP_ELEM_VARGS(fn, ...) fn(DT_N_S_mygpio, gpios, 0, __VA_ARGS__) \
    fn(DT_N_S_mygpio, gpios, 1, __VA_ARGS__) \
    fn(DT_N_S_mygpio, gpios, 2, __VA_ARGS__) \
    fn(DT_N_S_mygpio, gpios, 3, __VA_ARGS__)
#define DT_N_S_mygpio_P_gpios_FOREACH_PROP_ELEM_SEP_VARGS(fn, sep, ...) fn(DT_N_S_mygpio, gpios, 0, __VA_ARGS__) DT_DEBRACKET_INTERNAL sep \
    fn(DT_N_S_mygpio, gpios, 1, __VA_ARGS__) DT_DEBRACKET_INTERNAL sep \
    fn(DT_N_S_mygpio, gpios, 2, __VA_ARGS__) DT_DEBRACKET_INTERNAL sep \
    fn(DT_N_S_mygpio, gpios, 3, __VA_ARGS__)
#define DT_N_S_mygpio_P_gpios_LEN 4
#define DT_N_S_mygpio_P_gpios_EXISTS 1
#define DT_N_S_mygpio_P_status "okay"
#define DT_N_S_mygpio_P_status_STRING_UNQUOTED okay
#define DT_N_S_mygpio_P_status_STRING_TOKEN okay
#define DT_N_S_mygpio_P_status_STRING_UPPER_TOKEN OKAY
#define DT_N_S_mygpio_P_status_IDX_0 "okay"
#define DT_N_S_mygpio_P_status_IDX_0_EXISTS 1
#define DT_N_S_mygpio_P_status_ENUM_IDX 1
#define DT_N_S_mygpio_P_status_ENUM_VAL_okay_EXISTS 1
#define DT_N_S_mygpio_P_status_ENUM_TOKEN okay
#define DT_N_S_mygpio_P_status_ENUM_UPPER_TOKEN OKAY
#define DT_N_S_mygpio_P_status_FOREACH_PROP_ELEM(fn) fn(DT_N_S_mygpio, status, 0)
#define DT_N_S_mygpio_P_status_FOREACH_PROP_ELEM_SEP(fn, sep) fn(DT_N_S_mygpio, status, 0)
#define DT_N_S_mygpio_P_status_FOREACH_PROP_ELEM_VARGS(fn, ...) fn(DT_N_S_mygpio, status, 0, __VA_ARGS__)
#define DT_N_S_mygpio_P_status_FOREACH_PROP_ELEM_SEP_VARGS(fn, sep, ...) fn(DT_N_S_mygpio, status, 0, __VA_ARGS__)
#define DT_N_S_mygpio_P_status_LEN 1
#define DT_N_S_mygpio_P_status_EXISTS 1
#define DT_N_S_mygpio_P_compatible {"zephyr,mygpio"}
#define DT_N_S_mygpio_P_compatible_IDX_0 "zephyr,mygpio"
#define DT_N_S_mygpio_P_compatible_IDX_0_STRING_UNQUOTED zephyr,mygpio
#define DT_N_S_mygpio_P_compatible_IDX_0_STRING_TOKEN zephyr_mygpio
#define DT_N_S_mygpio_P_compatible_IDX_0_STRING_UPPER_TOKEN ZEPHYR_MYGPIO
#define DT_N_S_mygpio_P_compatible_IDX_0_EXISTS 1
#define DT_N_S_mygpio_P_compatible_FOREACH_PROP_ELEM(fn) fn(DT_N_S_mygpio, compatible, 0)
#define DT_N_S_mygpio_P_compatible_FOREACH_PROP_ELEM_SEP(fn, sep) fn(DT_N_S_mygpio, compatible, 0)
#define DT_N_S_mygpio_P_compatible_FOREACH_PROP_ELEM_VARGS(fn, ...) fn(DT_N_S_mygpio, compatible, 0, __VA_ARGS__)
#define DT_N_S_mygpio_P_compatible_FOREACH_PROP_ELEM_SEP_VARGS(fn, sep, ...) fn(DT_N_S_mygpio, compatible, 0, __VA_ARGS__)
#define DT_N_S_mygpio_P_compatible_LEN 1
#define DT_N_S_mygpio_P_compatible_EXISTS 1
#define DT_N_S_mygpio_P_wakeup_source 0
#define DT_N_S_mygpio_P_wakeup_source_EXISTS 1
#define DT_N_S_mygpio_P_zephyr_pm_device_runtime_auto 0
#define DT_N_S_mygpio_P_zephyr_pm_device_runtime_auto_EXISTS 1
```

Then I have checked zephyr.map file and it does not have any references to `__device_dts_ord_17`. So there must be some sort of issue, but I am unable to find it.

All of the default peripherals are working, and for example, using `gpioa` node works fine

Comment: Instead of just the error message itself, you need to provide (a lot more) context.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're facing an issue during final linking stage only (and rest of device tree settings look good) so my suspect would be towards `STM32_GPIO` module getting built. So can you check if you have following settings enabled in zephyr `.config` file under build folder? If they're not enabled then need to enable those in your board configuration file.

```
CONFIG_STM32_GPIO=y
CONFIG_DT_HAS_ST_STM32_GPIO_ENABLED=y
```